# UpdateNonDefaults is ignoring boolean parameters set to false

Tags: boolean, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to update a record in my SQL server 2012 Express DB using UpdateNonDefaults.
Boolean fields which are set to false are getting ignored as can be seen from the SQL statement.

How can I set DB value to false for boolean fields using UpdateNonDefaults?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have the same problem. Any resolution?

Comment: Actually it is good to note that this behaviour does create invalid SQL statement when you are trying to update only the boolean property. It will create a sql like: UPDATE <table> SET <empty> WHERE <where-clause> which is invalid because set-clause is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code, or we can't tell what is wrong...

Try:

```
[Default(typeof(bool?), null)] 
public bool? Foo {get;set;}
```

Or try :

```
[Default(typeof(int?), null)] 
public int? Foo {get; set;}
```

See if it works?

Comment: To reproduce the problem just add a bool? property to your model and try UpdateNonDefault on that object and set the bool? property to false. If you look at the generated SQL UPDATE statement you will see that the SET clause does not contain the bool? property setting. But if you try to set the same bool? property to true using UpdateNonDefaults it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, I have changed my "bool" data types to "string" and am using bool.FalseString and bool.TrueString to set my values. Not nice...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ideal solution but I used anonymous type as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#update) to update the null-able boolean field and it worked.

> One way to limit the fields which gets updated is to use an Anonymous
>   Type:
>
> ```
> db.Update<Person>(new { FirstName = "JJ" }, p => p.LastName == "Hendrix");
> ```

Does anyone know why UpdateNonDefaults does not update boolean values to false?

Answer (score 0):

While you call the UpdateNonDefaults method, it generates sql via the method ToUpdateStatement in SqlExpression.cs

```
public virtual string ToUpdateStatement(T item, bool excludeDefaults = false)
{
    var setFields = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var fieldDef in modelDef.FieldDefinitions)
    {
        if (fieldDef.ShouldSkipUpdate()) continue;
        if (fieldDef.IsRowVersion) continue;
        if (updateFields.Count > 0 && !updateFields.Contains(fieldDef.Name)) continue; // added

        var value = fieldDef.GetValue(item);
        if (excludeDefaults && (value == null || value.Equals(value.GetType().GetDefaultValue()))) continue; //GetDefaultValue?

        fieldDef.GetQuotedValue(item, DialectProvider);

        if (setFields.Length > 0)
            setFields.Append(", ");

        setFields
            .Append(DialectProvider.GetQuotedColumnName(fieldDef.FieldName))
            .Append("=")
            .Append(DialectProvider.GetQuotedValue(value, fieldDef.FieldType));
    }

    return string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET {1} {2}",
        DialectProvider.GetQuotedTableName(modelDef), setFields, WhereExpression);
}
```

Please note the line:

```
if (excludeDefaults && (value == null || value.Equals(value.GetType().GetDefaultValue()))) continue; //GetDefaultValue?
```

When you update a nullable boolean value from true to false, here the **value** is **fasle**, and **value.GetType()** is actually **typeof(bool)** while **not typeof(bool?)**, so value.GetType().GetDefaultValue() is always false.
Then, this column is ignored...

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239823/servicestack-ormlite-updatenondefaults-for-nullable-type-field