# ServiceStack Ormlite UpdateNonDefaults for nullable type field

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Please refer [UpdateNonDefaults is ignoring boolean parameters set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29238844/1799100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bool` properties are now always included in `UpdateNonDefaults()` [with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/bb526d4b262ef0b4d9aacaf64b96b8245a73afd8) which will let you do the following:

```
public class Poco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Bool { get; set; }
}

var db = OpenDbConnection();
db.DropAndCreateTable<Poco>();

db.Insert(new Poco { Id = 1, Bool = true });
db.UpdateNonDefaults(new Poco { Bool = false }, x => x.Id == 1);
var row = db.SingleById<Poco>(1);
row.Bool // false
```

This change is available from **v4.0.39+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Sorry but i have this problem yet. My version is 5.8.+

Comment: @white.devils don't just post an info-less comment, open a new question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).